# How to serialize a complex map in java to JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am facing a problem while serializing map of maps(or lists) into JSON. It can be upto any level. I am using GSON to convert map into JSON but I am not getting the desired output. Consider an example below:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", new ArrayList<String>(){{add("value2");add("value3");}});
```

When I serialize this map, I get to the following output:

```
{
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "[value2, value3]"
}
```

It gets worse when I have map inside a map. The output which I want is:

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : ["value2", "value3"]
}
```

Any idea how to get such output? I have already tried ObjectMapper and GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter but haven't got success so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put("key1", "value1");
 map.put("key2", Arrays.asList("value2", "value3")); String json = new Gson().toJson(map)` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's valid to store an ArrayList in a HashMap where a String is expected. I would've said that that code should fail, but I guess it must be succeeding, since it's not failing for you, and so what I'm assuming is happening is that when you insert it into the HashMap Java is actually calling toString() on it behind the scenes to cast it to String. So the value sitting in the HashMap is not actually an array; it was a string from the moment it was inserted. Thus, you're losing information that can't be salvaged downstream from the lossage.

Comment: bang on sir! The map was dynamically generated from program and at some point, toString() was being used while putting list into the map. I removed that toString() and now the code work fine!
Thanks for an awesome reply!

Comment: And yes, my Map is of <String, Object> and not <String, String>. I did a mistake while posting the question. A blessing in disguise I should say.